# How to determine if a voltage is regulated and rectified using AN8008 multimeter?

Tags: voltage-regulator, multimeter

Sorry, but this is probably a stupid question.

I have a motorbike and I need to find a wire that provides a fully regulated and rectified DC voltage. Especially at idle, a load like an LED light will flicker when it's not attached to a regulated and rectified wire. The main headlight receives an unregulated voltage on my bike.

I have the AN8008 multimeter:

[https://www.amazon.com/ANENG-AN8008-Multimeter-Resistance-Capacitance/dp/B076GZK62B](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076GZK62B)

I want to use it to test various devices in the front of the bike to see if any of the wires are providing a regulated and rectified voltage, but I don't know which mode I should use. The frequency varies tremendously with engine RPM, and when I test the voltage it reads ~12V, but that doesn't tell me if the frequency is staying steady or not.

Answer (score 1):

Puh, that's a multimeter, and not an oscilloscope. This might limit its usefulness for this purpose.

Anyway, you can try putting it into AC mode; where it reads a high AC voltage, you have ripples. That's not a very good measure, though, because it will neither detect strong fluctuations beyond the bandwidth of your measurement device, which will still interfere with your loads, nor will it allow assessment of what happens when you actually attach a load to that power rail, so it might detect things that don't matter.

In all honesty: on motorcycle wiring, unless you're already taking your voltage from within an electronic instrument, assume nothing is smooth. Nothing.

Instead, you'd want to add your own ESD-protected  voltage smoothing capacitors and a voltage regulator. There's not that much way around that.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I wasn't sure if I was missing a feature on my multimeter that could give me an idea of voltage fluctuation. I measured it in AC mode a couple weeks ago and I think it just read ~12V or something at idle, which doesn't really tell me anything. 12V at idle, 14V at running speed, but what I really what to know is if there is much pulsing. I think at this point the easiest way to test is to just hook up a motorcycle light bulb and use that to probe different connections. If the bulb flickers, don't use that wire, lol.

Comment: On the motorcycle, there are connections that are smooth *enough* because I have found a couple that don't flicker like the main headlight wiring does, but those unfortunately seem to be wired into the blinker circuit ><